# SSMS 18 and Source Control Integration ie. TFS

Tags: git, tfs, version-control, ssms-18

I am able to get Team menu in `SSMS 17.x` by following steps described [here](https://dba2o.wordpress.com/2018/07/23/enable-source-control-in-ssms/)

Now, I have upgraded to `SSMS 18.4` and I am able to get Source Control Option in Tools Menu --> Options by changing `ssms.pkgundef` file at location `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE` `ssms.pkgundef`

I have VS 2017 Installed in my machine. 
My question is, how can I get **Team Foundation Server** coming in Source control option. right now, it shows "none".

[SSMS-18 does not show TFS in Tools->Options->Source Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44UoV.png)

Comment: I found in [this blog](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2016/11/21/source-control-in-sql-server-management-studio-ssms/) from Microsoft, it said "The packages related to TFS Source Control features **must be removed** from the pkgundef file. This can be done by either deleting the section or commenting out each line using ‘//’"

Comment: upto SSMS 17.x - the above thing works perfectly but in SSMS 18.x, there aren't any packages related to TFS in pkgundef. what can we do for SSMS 18 ?

Comment: There is not a solution for SSMS 18 source control integration with TFS currently. Please use SSDT instead as suggested in [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aa28043f-b67b-434b-9a3e-318aa9bf4e4a/ssms-18-and-tfs-where-and-how?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade). Please vote it up in this [user voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32896402-bring-back-tfs-and-git-in-ssms)

Comment: oh, isn't there any alternative apart from SSDT or any 3rd party tools ?

Comment: You can try downloading [Team Explorer](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=TeamExplorer&rel=15) (e.g. TFS Client Tools), Or try the solution [here](https://forum.red-gate.com/discussion/85711/sql-source-control-integration-problems-with-ssms-18-2). or just use Git client as source control.